# highcharts lines colors change but I don't want to

Tags: highcharts

I'm using HighCharts to render two charts on a web page. I download the data for each charts dynamically with jquery and set the two charts with a `setChart` function.

```
function setChart(chart, name, data){
    while (chart.series.length > 0) {
        chart.series[0].remove(true);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        chart.addSeries({
            name: name[i],
            data: data[i],
        });
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when I download new datas with the jquery (= not refreshing the page), all the lines colors change.

How can I prevent HighCharts from changing the lines (=series) colors ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create an array with colours you need. Lets call it `colors`. It has to have enough number of elements or else you will get out of bound error.

```
function setChart(chart, name, data){
    while (chart.series.length > 0) {
        chart.series[0].remove(true);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        chart.addSeries({
            name: name[i],
            data: data[i],
            color: colors[i],
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And you can get default colors from Highcharts this way: `var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;`

Answer (score 0):

I mixed the two things in :

```
color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i % 10]
```

It work fine. The only thing that could be cool is it might be more than 10 colors, but I don't want to make them myself ^^

Thanks a lot ;)